# preg_match php, forming the pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So out of all of my php skills, I just suck at regular expressions. I totally understand the concept of it, but I can't write my patterns well.  Well I need them for to extract date information from a file path.  Here's my code:

```
#example path   
$path='/Users/landonsilla/Desktop/HS Pilot Project/Archive/Cabinet/Documents/2006-11In/Car Park/AR190298.doc';

echo $path."\n\n";
$pattern1 = '/[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}/';#match YYYYMMDD
$pattern2 = '/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}/';#match YYYY MM DD
$pattern3 = '/[0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}/';#match YYYY-MM
$pattern4 = '/20[0-9]{2}/';#match YYYY

if(preg_match($pattern1, $path, $matches)){
    $ret=$matches[0].'-'.$matches[1].'-'.$matches[2].' 00:00:00';
}
else if(preg_match($pattern2, $path, $matches)){
    $ret=$matches[0].'-'.$matches[1].'-'.$matches[2].' 00:00:00';
}
else if(preg_match($pattern3, $path, $matches)){
    $ret=$matches[0].'-'.$matches[1].'-01 00:00:00';
}
else if(preg_match($pattern4, $path, $matches)){
    $ret=$matches[0].'-01-01 00:00:00';
}
else{
    $ret=date ("Y-m-d H:i:s.", filemtime($path));
}
```

The $pattern1,2,3,4 variables just don't work.  Can somebody please let me know how to change those variables such that I can wind up having $ret be a date in my standard (mysql) format?

Comment: You have no groups for the suppatterns of which matches you use. `var_dump()` is your friend, start with single patterns in a test-file, debug until you get your results.

Comment: http://rubular.com is a great test tool.

Comment: well i'm using print_r() (same thing as var_dump in this case), but i can't seem to get multiple values out of the one string with one function call

Comment: @deceze, thanks for the url, that's a fun tool to play with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need to group your subpatterns using `()`. This will store the results in the `matches[]` array as you assumed. Further more the matches are stored in index 1 and up so you need to add 1 to each of your matches in your if/else.

```
$path='/Users/landonsilla/Desktop/HS Pilot Project/Archive/Cabinet/Documents/2002-11In/Car Park/AR190298.doc';

echo $path."\n\n";
$pattern1 = '/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/';#match YYYYMMDD
$pattern2 = '/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/';#match YYYY MM DD
$pattern3 = '/([0-9]{4})[-]([0-9]{2})/';#match YYYY-MM
$pattern4 = '/(20[0-9]{2})/';#match YYYY

if(preg_match($pattern1, $path, $matches)){
    $ret=$matches[1].'-'.$matches[2].'-'.$matches[3].' 00:00:00';
}
else if(preg_match($pattern2, $path, $matches)){
    $ret=$matches[1].'-'.$matches[2].'-'.$matches[3].' 00:00:00';
}
else if(preg_match($pattern3, $path, $matches)){
    $ret=$matches[1].'*-*'.$matches[2].'-01 00:00:00';
}
else if(preg_match($pattern4, $path, $matches)){
    $ret=$matches[1].'-01-01 00:00:00';
}
else{
    $ret=date ("Y-m-d H:i:s.", filemtime($path));
}
```

Result can be viewed on [here](http://ideone.com/XMc8x).

Comment: great! that's exactly what i wanted, i looks like i was close, i just didn't know about the grouping with parens and the additional offset in the resulting array.